# HTML table scraping in python - trouble finding tables on some pages

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from the price table on this website: https://www.letsrecycle.com/prices/textiles/textile-prices-2012/

I am unable to find the table using both read_html and BeautifulSoup, which is odd because I'm able to find the tables on other similar pages (e.g. https://www.letsrecycle.com/prices/metals/steel-cans/steel-can-prices-2018/)

I've tried playing with different parsers, but that didn't help. The relevant portion of my code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib    
url = 'http://www.letsrecycle.com/prices/textiles/textiles-prices-2012'
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
dfs = pd.read_html(webpage)
```

I also tried various BeautifulSoup parsers, such as:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html5lib")
table = soup.findAll("table")
table
```

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue - it was an inconsistent URL.
E.g. for 2006 the URL is:
https://www.letsrecycle.com/prices/textiles/textiles-prices-2006/
(textiles/textiles - with an 's')

but for 2012 the URL is:
https://www.letsrecycle.com/prices/textiles/textile-prices-2012/
(textiles/textile - no 's')

This is why my code couldn't find any tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need headers:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.letsrecycle.com/prices/textiles/textile-prices-2012/', headers=headers)
dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
print(dfs)
```

Output:

```
[                  0          1          2  ...          4          5          6
0              2012    January   February  ...      April        May       June
1     Textile banks  270 - 340  260 - 350  ...  260 - 360  260 - 360  260 - 350
2  Shop collections  490 - 550  500 - 560  ...  500 - 560  500 - 570  510 - 580
3      Charity rags  580 - 650  600 - 670  ...  610 - 700  620 - 700  620 - 720

[4 rows x 7 columns],                   0          1          2  ...          4          5          6
0              2012       July     August  ...    October   November   December
1     Textile banks  250 - 350  250 - 330  ...  260 - 340  260 - 340  250 - 340
2  Shop collections  520 - 590  530 - 590  ...  530 - 580  540 - 590  530 - 580
3      Charity rags  630 - 730  640 - 740  ...  650 - 730  650 - 730  640 - 730

[4 rows x 7 columns]]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your assistance.
I'm afraid I tried your code verbatim, and I still got an error (ValueError: No tables found) - which is the same error I have been experiencing.

Comment: Strange because without headers I also get ValueError but with headers it works like a charm. @stormcrow03